# Pandas: Multi Index hierarchical join - populating missing level values from one join side

Tags: python, pandas

I have some hierarchical data. Portions of it are scattered through 2 files.

The first file contains all hierarchy levels, but due to circumstances outside of my control, sometimes rows for particular level *values* are ommitted (the external system that produces the data omits rows where the value is 0.)

Here is an example. Key INFO: **We want to always have 3 leaf levels**

```
node1
  + child1
      + leaf1 # NB: this child has no value for leaf2
      + leaf3
  + child2
      + leaf1
      + leaf2
      + leaf3
node2
  ... etc

In tabular:

  level1  level2 level3  value1
0  node1  child1  leaf1      10
1  node1  child1  leaf3      30
2  node1  child2  leaf1      10
3  node1  child2  leaf3      30
4  node2  child1  leaf1     100
5  node2  child1  leaf2     200
6  node2  child1  leaf3     200
7  node2  child2  leaf1     300
8  node2  child2  leaf2     400
9  node2  child2  leaf3     500
```

The second file contains the lowest hierarchy level (the leaves of the hierarchy tree) - usefully this file always contains data for every possible leaf value.

```
  level3  value2
0  leaf1    1000
1  leaf2    2000
2  leaf3    3000
```

I was wondering if there was a way to join these two to ensure the resulting dataframe has ALL leaf level values in all nodes. The ommitted values can be zero or nan filled. Like this.

```
                      value2  value1
level1 level2 level3                
node1  child1 leaf1     1000    10.0
              leaf2     2000     0.0
              leaf3     3000    30.0
node2  child1 leaf1     1000   100.0
              leaf2     2000   200.0
              leaf3     3000   200.0
node1  child2 leaf1     1000    10.0
              leaf2     2000     0.0
              leaf3     3000    30.0
node2  child2 leaf1     1000   300.0
              leaf2     2000   400.0
              leaf3     3000   500.0
```

I've some code that accomplishes this, but I cannot help thinking that there must be a MUCH simpler way to accomplish this - perhaps through some kind of join or concat. However, none of those sorts I've tried actually works.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# NB: 
#  1. The size of level1 is not known in advance. Actual
#     data may have few or many values.
#  2. The level3 values are ommitted when value1 is zero.
#     (This is the problem I want to solve)
#  3. level2 does have a set number of values (child1, child2)
#     - I'd prefer to avoid using that, but can do so.
data1 = """
level1,level2,level3,value1
node1,child1,leaf1,10
node1,child1,leaf3,30
node1,child2,leaf1,10
node1,child2,leaf3,30
node2,child1,leaf1,100
node2,child1,leaf2,200
node2,child1,leaf3,200
node2,child2,leaf1,300
node2,child2,leaf2,400
node2,child2,leaf3,500
"""

# This data ALWAYS has the full number of level2 values.
data2 = """
level3,value2
leaf1,1000
leaf2,2000
leaf3,3000
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1))
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2))
#result_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(desired_result), index_col=[0,1]).fillna(0.0)

print("Input data1:")
print(df1)

print("Input data2:")
print(df2)

# Here is how I got this to work.

# Shave off level1 and 2 from df1, and drop duplicates.
# that gives us only the hierarchy data for L1 and L2.
hierarchy1_df = df1[['level1', 'level2']].drop_duplicates()

print("Level1 and Level2 hierarchy:")
print(hierarchy1_df)
#Level1 and Level2 hierarchy:
#  level1  level2
#0  node1  child1
#2  node1  child2
#4  node2  child1
#7  node2  child2

# I will abuse the fact that level2 has a static number of
# values. I will add level2 to df2 and duplicate
# the other column data over that new dimension.
child1_df = df2.copy()
child1_df['level2'] = 'child1'

child2_df = df2.copy()
child2_df['level2'] = 'child2'

hierarchy2_df = pd.concat([child1_df, child2_df])
print("Level2 and Level3 hierarchy")
print(hierarchy2_df)

#Level2 and Level3 hierarchy
#  level3  value2  level2
#0  leaf1    1000  child1
#1  leaf2    2000  child1
#2  leaf3    3000  child1
#0  leaf1    1000  child2
#1  leaf2    2000  child2
#2  leaf3    3000  child2

# Now I will join this to hierarchy1_df. That will give us
# all of level1, level2, and level3.
hierarchy_df = pd.merge(hierarchy1_df, hierarchy2_df, on=['level2'])
hierarchy_df = hierarchy_df.set_index(['level1', 'level2', 'level3'])
print("Full hierarchy:")
print(hierarchy_df)

#Full hierarchy:
#                      value2
#level1 level2 level3        
#node1  child1 leaf1     1000
#              leaf2     2000
#              leaf3     3000
#node2  child1 leaf1     1000
#              leaf2     2000
#              leaf3     3000
#node1  child2 leaf1     1000
#              leaf2     2000
#              leaf3     3000
#node2  child2 leaf1     1000
#              leaf2     2000
#              leaf3     3000


# And finally I join the full hierarchy back to df1 which should
# give us the desired result:
df1 = df1.set_index(['level1', 'level2', 'level3'])


df = hierarchy_df.join(df1).fillna(0.0)
print("Desired Result")
print(df)
```

Will accept the answer below, but using that answer found this way of also accomplishing:

```py
# Get the first 2 levels from df1. df1 has all the values for
# those.
parent_levels = df1.set_index(['level1','level2']).index.levels
# The final level from df2, which has all the level values
# for level3.
df2 = df2.set_index(['level3'])

# Create a hierarchical index that is the product
# of all 3 levels.
hierarchy = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    parent_levels + [df2.index],
    names=['level1', 'level2', 'level3'])

# Push the new index into df1, filling empty rows
# with 0s.
df = (df1.set_index(['level1','level2', 'level3'])
        .reindex(hierarchy)
        .fillna(0.0)
        .join(df2)
)

# Done.
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for add missing values - for correct ouput need all unique values from `df2['level3']` in `df1['level3']`:

```
df = df1.set_index(['level1','level2','level3']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack()

d = df2.set_index('level3')['value2']
df.insert(0, 'value2', df.index.get_level_values('level3').map(d))
print (df)
                      value2  value1
level1 level2 level3                
node1  child1 leaf1     1000      10
              leaf2     2000       0
              leaf3     3000      30
       child2 leaf1     1000      10
              leaf2     2000       0
              leaf3     3000      30
node2  child1 leaf1     1000     100
              leaf2     2000     200
              leaf3     3000     200
       child2 leaf1     1000     300
              leaf2     2000     400
              leaf3     3000     500
```

EDIT: If possible not exist some element, you can add it by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df1.set_index(['level1','level2','level3'])['value1']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(df2['level3'], axis=1)
         .stack()
         .to_frame(name='value1'))

d = df2.set_index('level3')['value2']
df.insert(0, 'value2', df.index.get_level_values('level3').map(d))
print (df)
                      value2  value1
level1 level2 level3                
node1  child1 leaf1     1000      10
              leaf2     2000       0
              leaf3     3000      30
       child2 leaf1     1000      10
              leaf2     2000       0
              leaf3     3000      30
node2  child1 leaf1     1000     100
              leaf2     2000     200
              leaf3     3000     200
       child2 leaf1     1000     300
              leaf2     2000     400
              leaf3     3000     500
```

Comment: I like the unstack and fill, but unfortunately this does not work if df1 does not contain at least on instance of leaf2 somewhere in one of the nodes - which won't necessarily be the case.